# How to search for data based on the suffix?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+-----------+
| id |   title   |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | greating  |
| 2  | colors    |
| 3  | dislike   |
+----+-----------+
```

Actually I want this output:

```
'color'  =>  nothing found
'colors' =>  second row selected
'great'  =>  nothing found
'like'   =>  third row selected
```

Here is my query: (But does not work)

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST(*$anything IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So, How can I implement that?

---

- It should be noted that this works: (perfix)

  `... $anything* IN BOOLEAN MODE`

But as I said, I need to suffix (not perfix)

---

- It should be noted, I can do that using `LIKE` caluse, like this:

  `... WHERE title LIKE %$anything`

But I want to do that using `MATCH()`.